# Missing URL error on VIEW Intent filter if I specify mimeType for action PICK

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an app that could view different kinds of video files using intent filters from different sources. To allow the app to appears always as choice when I try to open whatever video file, I have placed this code in the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
  <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

So I can receive the Uri in the app handling It in the main activity.

Although everything seems working as supposed, every time that I try to edit the manifest Android Studio marks all intent filter code with a red underline reporting the error `missing url`. 
The error disappears If I remove `<data android:mimeType="video/*" />` but If I do this the app appears as choice not only for video files.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 8):

The guys at Google seem to like hinting rather than answering questions [deep-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

It is important to specify the schema correctly. For files in older versions it is "file", in newer versions of Android it is "content". For links, these are http and https.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
        android:host="*"
        android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext"
        android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
        android:host="*"
        android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext"
        android:scheme="content" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 5):

@AndreaF I have tha same issue. You can just suppress this warning.

To suppress try this:

```
<intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
  <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" to your initial manifest tag if it's not already there.

Comment: Well this is an ugly solution

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be pretty if it works...it worked for me while porting and old app to API29

Answer (score 0):

Prompt missing url not because `action.PICK`, the error related to `action.VIEW`

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>  //delete this line
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>  //add this line
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/> //and this
  <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

for `action.VIEW`,you could define a different intent-filter.

Comment: I know that error is related to action VIEW as stated in the title of my question. The problem is that I want to have both action PICK and VIEW and I don't understand why this error happens only if there is the mimeType line. Using your code I lost the ability to get action.VIEW intent that is a worse (as I have said the app works despite the error mark in Android Studio editor)