# android.intent.action.VIEW & mimeType have 'missing URL' ERROR in Manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest, intentfilter

I am trying to use [this open-source](https://github.com/Kiritor/MyLoveReader/blob/master/LoveReader6.0/AndroidManifest.xml).

And It occurs `missing URL` errors.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-cbz" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xps" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbz" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The ERRORs occur with these:

```
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-cbz" />
```

or this:

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

If I delete either one, the red lines go away. However, This is not what I expect. I do need diverse `intent-filter` for different usages.

How can I fix this??

Ref: [Missing URL error on VIEW Intent filter if I specify mimeType for action PICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506871/missing-url-error-on-view-intent-filter-if-i-specify-mimetype-for-action-pick)